# System design interview questions

Tags: architecture, system

As a new grad attending interviews, I feel that the sections I do the worst are in system design questions like `How will you design a search engine?` Or `How do you support google like instant responses`

I make answers and it sounds convincing to me, but I feel I can do better by studying such systems themselves to get an understanding of the problems that arise and needs to be solved. Can the community point me to resources (blogs, online classes, text books, white papers, academic publications anything.,) to help me along this task?

Answer (score 3):

Some articles and books about architecture:

- [PEAA](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/)
- [EIP](http://eaipatterns.com/toc.html)
- [Software Systems architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032171833X)
- [Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471958697)
- [Distributed Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132143011)

And of course the regular design pattern books.

- [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

Answer (score 3):

I interview people.  A fair bit.

FYI: If you're a new grad, I basically couldn't care less about your design skills.  If you're otherwise good, you'll learn said skills over time through experience.  It's not something one can expect out of someone straight  out of college.  More than likely, you haven't built many non-trivial systems.  You don't have the experience to warrant major expectations.  If you have, double awesome!  But it's not an expectaction.

Comment: So it is acceptable for new grad be somehow naive on these questions?

Comment: IMHO yes, at best if they can think aloud, clear requirements and honestly try to solve these questions.